# Why do we need implicit differentiation in this related rates problem?

Tags: calculus

> Two people are 50 feet apart.  One of them starts walking north at a rate so that the angle shown in the diagram below is changing at a constant rate of 0.01 rad/min.  At what rate is distance between the two people changing when  radians?

[image]

so $\sec{\theta} = \frac{x}{50}$

and so I hear the next step is:

$\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta} \cdot \theta' = \frac{x'}{50}$

I don't get that step.

1. Why do we need implicit differentiation here? I thought the derivative of $\sec{\theta}$ was $\sec{\theta}\tan{\theta}$
2. Where did the right side come from?

Comment: you are probably differentiating wrt time $t$, so you need to apply the chain rule accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 2

Note that we have

$$\frac {d \cos(\theta)}{d \theta}=-\sin(\theta)$$
but
$$\frac {d \cos(\theta(t))}{dt}=\frac {d \cos(\theta(t))}{d \theta}\frac {d \theta}{dt}=-\sin(\theta(t)) \frac {d\theta }{dt}=-\sin(\theta(t)) \theta '$$

the derivative is not taken wrt $\theta$ but to t and $\theta=\theta(t)$
$$\sec{\theta} = \frac{x}{50} $$
$$\cos^{-1} (\theta)=\frac{x}{50} $$
You have the rule $(f^n)'=nf^{n-1} \times f'$
$$-1 \cos^{-2}(\theta)(-\sin (\theta)) \theta '=\frac{x'}{50}$$
$$ \cos^{-1} (\theta) \tan (\theta) \theta '=\frac{x'}{50}$$
$$ \sec (\theta) \tan (\theta) \theta '=\frac{x'}{50}$$

Comment: And the right side we just use quotient rule right?

Comment: And the right side we just use quotient rule right?

Comment: yes its normal differentiation rules @Jwan622

Comment: But doesn't x change in response to t too?

Comment: yes $x'=\frac {dx}{dt}$

Comment: Oh I seeeeeee I think

Comment: use chain rule for right side of the equation...@Jwan622